# Equivalence between joint and conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

I am studying conditional and joint probabilities, and a particular thought has me stumped. In a scenario with three different variables with binary outcomes, A, B, C and no independence or dependence assumptions, is the following always true?

```
P(A|B,C)*P(B|A,C)*P(C|B,C) = P(A,B,C)
```

My first assumption was no because I was aware that `P(A|B,C)*P(B|C)*P(C) = P(A,B,C)` regardless of independence assumptions. I thought adding in these addition dependences in the equation in question would mess things up and make the equivalency false.

Then I started thinking of some scenarios. If A, B, and C were all independent, then `P(A|B,C)*P(B|A,C)*P(C|B,C)` would reduce to `P(A)*P(B)*P(C)` and be equivalent to `P(A,B,C)`. Further, if you start with the expression `P(A|B,C)*P(B|A,C)*P(C|B,C)` and then, one by one, reduce it according to any independences, you would come to a more concise form of the expression, but it would still be equivalent to `P(A,B,C)`. Is this the case?

TLDR: is `P(A|B,C)*P(B|A,C)*P(C|B,C) = P(A,B,C)` true regardless of any independence assumptions?

Comment: Take $A=B=C$ as a counter-example.